# Transfer Learning with VGG16 Model Fit Error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, vgg-net, image-classification

I am new to transfer learning and cannot understand what is causing the following error: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)` when running `model.fit`. What could be leading to this problem?

```
   #created dataframes for training, validation, and testing
   #Example of what dataframe looks like:
   dataframe.head(1) 
        Sex    Weight    File
    0  female  124  1_124_3_20161220221743058.jpg
```

```
    weight_label = df.columns[1]
    sex_label = df.columns[0]
    labels = [classlabel for classlabel in df.columns[:2]]

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range = 40,
        width_shift_range = 0.4,
        height_shift_range = 0.4
    )

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    subfolder = "./training/"
    #Dataframe is simply partitioned as you would splitting by dataset
    training_dataframe, validation_dataframe, testing_dataframe

    train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=training_dataframe,
        directory=directory_dataset_path,
        x_col="file",
        y_col=labels,
        batch_size=32,
        seed=42,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode="raw"
       )

    valid_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=validation_dataframe,
        directory=directory_dataset_path,
        x_col="file",
        y_col=labels,
        batch_size=32,
        seed=42,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode="raw"
        )
```

```
    Base_VGG16 = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet',include_top = False)

    for layer in Base_VGG16[:12]:
        layer.trainable = False

    sex_model = Base_VGG16.output
    sex_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(sex_model)
    sex_model = Dropout(0.5)(sex_model)
    predict_sex = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(sex_model)

    weight_model = Base_VGG16.output
    weight_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(weight_model)
    weight_model = Dropout(0.5)(weight_model)
    predict_weight = Dense(1, activation='relu')(weight_model)
    model = Model(inputs=Base_VGG16.input, outputs=[predict_sex, predict_weight])

    model.compile(loss =['binary_crossentropy','mae'],
              optimizer=SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy','mae'])

    history=model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=5000 // 32,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=valid_generator,
        validation_steps=1500 // 32
    )
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code, the `train_generator` and `valid_generator` definitions seem to not be in your given snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added code for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object dtypes of dataframe might not be in proper format.
Use `training_dataframe.info()` to know the dtypes. ALso check whether there is any NaN values in your dataframe or not

```
training_dataframe['Weight'] = training_dataframe['Weight'].astype(int)
```

Also try to use Encoders to encode categorical features

Comment: Thanks. That is super helpful. Types are: `dtypes: int64(1), object(2)` so I need to convert the two objects types to int64 correct?

Comment: Yes, incorrect dtypes can cause this type of problem.

Comment: Just to confirm, is my understanding correct that running `model.fit` on a `dtypes: object` will result in an error? Objects cannot be processed and must first be converted?

Comment: Yes, ML models do not understand categorical data. So it should be encoded.